# How to register for “Apps using location” on the Mac

Tags: macos, core-location

I’m playing with Wi-Fi Positioning system (WPS) on the Mac.

Attempting to specify the most exact positioning possible. I’ve noticed that apps such as Maps register in the Location notification of the OS

[image]

Yet my code does not seem to generate this effect,

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1; // meters

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app sandboxed?
If it is, you need to enable the "App Data" -> "Location" entitlement in the "Capabilities" tab of your target.
Otherwise the `CLLocationManager` silently fails to start.

Another interesting point is, that your app only shows up in this list when the `CLLocationManager` is actually running. Calling `stopUpdatingLocation` deregisters your app from the location agent.

A minimal entitlement file for a OS X app using Core Location looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.personal-information.location</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hello weichsel, I’m running from Xcode. Do I need to “sandbox” my app from the development environment as well? The funny this is that location manager is able to report correct lat,lng I’m just wondering if it’s the “most accurate” it can because of not registering for “Apps Using Location”.

Comment: For me, Core Location only (silently) failed when sandboxing was enabled without specifying the com.apple.security.personal-information.location entitlement. When sandboxing wasn't enabled at all, CL worked fine. How are you obtaining the latitude? Is CLManager calling your delegate methods (e.g. locationManager: manager:didUpdateToLocation:)

Comment: Yes, 
2014-03-28 14:17:27.119 AirTest[84749:303] locationManager:didUpdateLocations (
    “<+32.07416032,+34.77531060> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/28/14, 2:17:27 PM Israel Daylight Time"
)

also I’ve now educated myself on sandboxing. My app is not currently sandboxed.

Comment: I noticed that most application entries (including Maps.app) vanish from the menu icon after some time. Even when the apps are still running & reporting location data. Is the icon displayed after your launch the app or isn't it showing up at all?

Comment: Not at all. Maps disappears because it does small polling for location data. If you for ex. put the app back into focus it will appear again, as it attempting to triangulate your current location again. That’s why the “blue dot” appears after some time that the app is opened and in focus.